# insert mode Abbreviations work in command mode, but not in insert mode

Tags: neovim, abbreviations

I have:

```
au BufRead,BufNewFile *.tex set filetype=tex
au BufRead,BufNewFile *.tex inoreabbrev ß \ss{}
au BufRead,BufNewFile *.tex inoreabbrev ö \"{o}
au BufRead,BufNewFile *.tex inoreabbrev ä \"{a}
au BufRead,BufNewFile *.tex inoreabbrev ü \"{u}
```

in my `filetype.vim`. When I open a TeX file and type `:ab`:

```
i  ü           * \"{u}                                                 
i  ä           * \"{a}                                                
i  ö           * \"{o}                                                
i  ß           * \ss{}

Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

- My abbreviations work in command line mode, `:ß` results in `:\ss{}`;
- but they don't in insert mode.

Why do my abbreviations only work in command line mode, but not in insert mode?

Comment: Can you post the rest of your .vimrc file? Also, are you typing another key after the abbreviation in order to fire it?

Comment: I used the space for firing it. my nvim config: https://github.com/toogley/dotfiles/tree/593f8f89b2e1633a27e9d501a3a639cb4f34380b/nvim

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT** the answer below doesn't count for the current release 0.2, both examples work there.

---

It seems that neovim was a bit buggy on this topic.

```
" works in neovim
:ab ms Microsoft


" doesn't work in neovim
:ab ß \ss{}
```

=> my solution was to move back to vim for now.

([my nvim config](https://github.com/toogley/dotfiles/tree/593f8f89b2e1633a27e9d501a3a639cb4f34380b/nvim))

Comment: In general, you *don't* want to type comments after abbreviations like this. Sooner or later, it *will* be interpreted as the right-hand side of an abbreviation since `"` is also used to quote strings. You're best off just giving comments their own line to sit on ;-)